# how to solve LP-relaxation with cplex

Tags: c++, cplex

I have an MIP model and I want to have the solution to its LP relaxation.

I didn't change my variable declaration, but at the end instead of

```
cplex_model.solve();
```

I wrote:

```
cplex_model.solveRelaxed();
```

But it gives me an error, saying solveRelaxed is not a member of IloCplex!
how can I get rid of this error?
Thanks

In order to use `Model.add(IloConversion(env, variable, ILOFLOAT));` for a matrix, should I use a for loop on one of it's dimensions?
In my case I have a matrix x(i,j) and an array z(j), and I write the conversion like this:

`for(IloInt i=0; i<I; i++){
Model.add(IloConversion(env, x[i], ILOFLOAT));
}
    Model.add(IloConversion(env, z, ILOFLOAT));`

Answer (score 5):

The documented way is to add IloConversion objects into the model: e.g.

```
model.add(IloConversion(env, binary_variable, ILOFLOAT));
```